# delete and add excel sheet programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, excel

i want to delete worksheet.and after that i want to create worksheet with same name(i want to remove all content in existing sheet so that replace option will not visible).
i am try this one

```
   var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
   xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\\excelsheet\\incomschedule.xlsx");
   xlApp.Worksheets[2].Delete();
   Excel.Worksheet sheet = xlApp.Worksheets[2].Add();
```

but this did not work properly.

Comment: what type of error your getting?

Comment: this one delete some rows from sheet2 not all rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = 
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\\excelsheet\\incomschedule.xlsx");
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[2];
worksheet.Delete();
book.Worksheets.Add();
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
book.Save();
book.Close();
```

Comment: Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[2];in this,there will be use another term for worksheet because class and object name can't be same

Comment: thank you very much this one help me to solve my problem

Comment: var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\\excelsheet\\incomschedule.xlsx");
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            book.Worksheets[2].Delete();
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Sheets.Add();

Answer (score 0):

```
   var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
   Excel.WorkBook book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\\excelsheet\\incomschedule.xlsx");
   book.Worksheets[2].Delete();
   Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Sheets.Add();
```

Comment: this one give error  'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'Add'

Comment: I'm sorry, the last statement is:"Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Sheets.Add(); "

Comment: new sheet is added successfully but sheet2 is also exist